# JavaFX 2.0 Resizing Textfield in Toolbar

Tags: javafx, textfield, toolbar

I'd like to resize a Textfiled located in a Toolbar. I created a NewSearchViewController instance class in the MainController and during initialization, I added a listener so when the windows change the Texfield get resized. But it does not work !

Any help, please ?

```
@FXML
private TextField searchTextField;

public NewSearchViewController() {  
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();  
    loader.setController(this);  
    loader.setRoot(this);  

    this.setScene(new Scene(this, 600, 450));  

    try {  
        loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fxml/NewSearchView.fxml"));  
    } catch (IOException ex) {  
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());  
    }   
}  

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {  
        searchTextField.setMinWidth(600);  
        searchTextField.setPrefWidth(600);  

        this.scene.widthProperty().addListener(  
                new ChangeListener() {  
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable,  
                    Object oldValue, Object newValue) {  
                Double width = (Double) newValue;  
                searchTextField.setPrefWidth(width);  
            }  
        });      
}
```

Comment: `stackoverflow.com/questions/19919241/gridpane-to-horizontally-vertically-fill-the-whole-stage` may this help you

Comment: Ok, I resolved it ! Just create a @FXML private AnchorPane rootAnchor; and add attach the listener to it. Thanks

Comment: thats sound good....you can vote up my answer

Answer (score -1):

Place your TextField inside an hbox than textField.hgrow as always